# Using a selector switch to change between a 12 V and 20 V battery

Tags: wiring, motor-controller

I am working on taking a 12 V system and introducing an alternate battery source that is a 20 V battery that is stepped down to 12 V with a RioRand 7-70 V PWM DC Motor Speed Controller Switch.  If I wire the setup as show in the picture, will I run into any issues?

[image: Wiring Diagram]

Comment: seems reasonable ... how are you charging the 20 V battery?

Comment: It's being removed and charged separate from the system. Haven't figured out a better solution yet.

Comment: It's reasonable as long as the load actually is a motor, as shown. Note that as the output of the speed controller is a series of 20 V pulses you can't connect any electronic load that expects a smooth 12 V DC.

Answer (score 1):

The wiring seems reasonable.

However you may encounter other problems.
PWM is prone to damage the insulation of motor windings if the motor isn't designed to take the additional voltage and spikes from the inductance.

On top of that you may encounter arcing over the insulating gaps of the commutator burning it or causing short circuit, as the creepage distances can be too small for the voltages generated.

Check the motor's data for hints concerning this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the appropriate schematic.

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear for the OP, the second pole of the switch disconnects the 20 V battery from the voltage controller when not in use. This prevents standby discharge.