# Simple switch between 12V and 24V

Tags: voltage, parallel, series

I hope somebody can help me here.

I am helping my son build a 24V race car with his school. We have a speed controller that runs on 24V built by an electronics engineer who is no longer with us. The 24V is supplied by two 12V batteries in series. To get a quicker start off the line, I want to fit a momentary boost button which will switch power from 24V to 12V, changing the batteries from series to parallel for a few moments to get going.

I have two 120A relays with five connections (two for power, and the rest with common, NC and NO.) I also have a momentary switch to switch the relays.

Can somebody help me with a a simple circuit to switch the batteries from series to parallel, bypassing the controller for the duration of boost. (Three wires, common, 12V from both batteries in parallel when momentary switch is depressed, and 24V when in normal mode.)

Race regulations do not allow extra batteries or motor modificatuions so this is what we have to work with.

I am sure this is simple, but I cannot get my head around it.

Comment: Why do you think that running a 24 volt motor on 12 volts will give you a "quicker start"?

Comment: Looks like the idea here is to parallel the batteries and apply that directly to the motor, bypassing any current limits in the controller @PeterBennett. fluffy dice: This would only make it faster if the controller or the series batteries are the bottleneck - have you verified this at all? Also the controller will probably lose power during boost and reset - does it have a lengthy boot up time?

Answer (score 1):

**SAFETY WARNING:** There is no safeties in the following circuit - relays could weld and prevent the vehicle from stopping, and the current draw could be extreme and start a fire or melt something. Even when it works without disaster it still has no control over the applied current, your only option is full throttle forward. Please make carefully sure that this is what you want and need before putting it together. I put this answer here because it *answers the question*, not because it it's the correct solution to the problem.

Here is a relay schematic I found on a forum. Note that this uses DPDT relays - you can make exactly one DPDT relay from the relays you have right now. All these relays should be *break before make* relays otherwise everything will short out and probably start a fire. Do use a fuse for each battery - children are our future you know.

RELAY1 is in charge of changing the batteries from series to parallel configuration, the default is series.

RELAY2 is in charge of disconnecting the motor controller from the motor and connecting the batteries for the uncontrolled burst of acceleration you're seeking.

I would put the relay coils in parallel on your turbo boost control button.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIWD77.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Schematic redrawn from this forum post:

https://maker.pro/forums/threads/batteries-in-series-charging-and-center-tapping.258084/#post-1535596

Comment: Thank you Bryan for your help. I will try to answer your questions. My reason for changinf the config from series to parallel for a few moments is to give a litte extra boost off the line. Even though the volage is half, the surge current provided shpoukld be grewter from two batteries in parallel, than in series. This is only to et going. Once moving the congi will be switched back to series for the rest of the race.  most of these cars are controlled by a simple on off switch on the steering, with no throttle control, and start at 24V from the off.

Comment: However as the race is an endurance race over two hours, losing that much current at the start has an effect on how you finish!. no battery change is allowed. The races are held at proper race tracks (goodwood, Thruxton, Silverstone and Dunsfold) with full mashalling, and the drivers have to show a quick escape if required as part of scrutineering, so in the unlikley event of a fire, It would be dealt with promptly.

Comment: Thank you for your circuit diagram. I too drew a similar circuit, but I was hoping to get away with two relays, instead of four, both for current draw reasons, and as its less components. The relays are rated at 100A, and I cannot locate any DPDT relays rated at that current. Also there is a fuse in line already, and a safety cut off switch, both of which are mandatory.

Comment: @Bryan how can we implement above schematic using transistor?

Comment: @BhushanWaghe that’s quite a different problem, worthy of its own question. You should open a new question and reference this one.

Comment: There is similar to a very similar question posted and discussed a couple years ago: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/601889/using-a-selector-switch-to-change-between-a-12-v-and-20-v-battery

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need is a short-term surge of 20-24V for both maximum speed and maximum torque, and then a half-speed configuration of 12 V (batteries in parallel). And I would think you would use a variable voltage controller for normal operation. Perhaps you can just use just an SPDT switch or relay to select full 24 V for the quick boost, and then back to variable 12-20 VDC for normal operation.

The controller probably has a slow-start circuit or current limiter that is causing the unwanted poor performance.